# Android to Google App Engine Gzip compression not working?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an Android app that sends data to the Google App Engine. I have been following this example: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints

My code which provides the app engine API in my app looks like this:

```
// Compression turned on
@Provides
ProbeDataSetApi provideProbeDataSetApi() {
    ProbeDataSetApi.Builder builder = new ProbeDataSetApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
            new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
            .setRootUrl("https://my_app_name.appspot.com/_ah/api/");
    return builder.build();
}

// Compression turned off
/*
@Provides
ProbeDataSetApi provideProbeDataSetApi() {
    ProbeDataSetApi.Builder builder = new ProbeDataSetApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
            new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
            .setRootUrl("https://my_app_name.appspot.com/_ah/api/");
            .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                @Override
                public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest) throws IOException {
                    abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                }
            });
    return builder.build();
}
*/
```

In my EndPoint, I get the value`(HttpServletRequest) request.getHeader("Content-Length")`. This value is approximately equal regardless of whether or not I have Gzip compression turned on in my app per the code above. For example, sending 20 datapoints is always 75KB regardless of whether compression is turned on. My raw data are very repetitive strings, and so I would think a great candidate for compression.

What is going on here?

1. Is the request not being compressed?
2. Is my data not as compressible as I think?
3. Is `(HttpServletRequest) request.getHeader("Content-Length")` reporting the uncompressed length? If so, how can I get the compressed size?
4. How can I find out for certain how many bytes are being transmitted by my app?

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

Lucas

Comment: Hi lucas, did you ever get to figure this out? Thanks!

Comment: @Albert no, I did not....